# How to set different font size for UIButton when it is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I am trying to change font size of button itself after it was pressed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonToResize: UIButton!

   @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        buttonToResize.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 40)
// Also tried buttonToResize.titleLabel?.font = UIFont .systemFont(ofSize: 4)
}
```

However the changes are not applied.

What is interesting, to me, that if I try to resize some other button (second one) after pressing on initial (first one), it works as expected.

Like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var buttonToResize: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var secondButtonToResize: UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    secondButtonToResize.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 40)
}
```

Other properties like backgroundColor seems to apply, however with font size I face problem.

Answer (score 4):

First, here's the sequence of events when you tap on a `UIButton`.

1. The button sets its own `isHighlighted` property to `true`.
2. The button fires any `Touch Down` actions, possibly multiple times if you drag your finger around.
3. The button fires any `Primary Action Triggered` actions (like your `buttonTapped`).
4. The button fires any `Touch Up` actions.
5. The button sets its own `isHighlighted` property to `false`.

*Every time isHighlighted changes, the button updates its styling to how it thinks it should look.* So a moment after `buttonTapped`, the button you pressed overwrites your chosen font with its own font.

It's worth exploring this to make sure you understand it by creating a `UIButton` subclass. **Don't use this in production**. Once you start overriding parts of UIButton, you need to override *all* of it.

```swift
// This class is to demonstrate the sequence of events when you press a UIButton.
// Do not use in production.
// To make this work properly, you would also have to override all the other properties that effect UIButton.state, and also UIButton.state itself.
class MyOverrideHighlightedButton : UIButton {
    // Define a local property to store our highlighted state.
    var myHighlighted : Bool = false
    
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        get {
            // Just return the existing property.
            return myHighlighted
        }
        
        set {
            print("Setting MyOverrideHighlightedButton.isHighlighted from \(myHighlighted) to \(newValue)")
            
            myHighlighted = newValue
            
            // Since the UIButton remains unaware of its highlighted state changing, we need to change its appearance here.
            // Use garish colors so we can be sure it works during testing.
            if (myHighlighted) {
                titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.red
            } else {
                titleLabel!.textColor = titleColor(for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So where does it keep pulling its old font from? On loading a view it will apply [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) settings, but those will get discarded when you press the button too. iOS 15+, it looks like it uses the new [UIButton.Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration) struct. So you could put this in your `buttonTapped`:

```swift
// The Configuration struct used here was only defined in iOS 15 and
// will fail in earlier versions.
// See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration
sender.configuration!.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
    var outgoing = incoming
    // We only want to change the font, but we could change other properties here too.
    outgoing.font = UIFont(name: "Zapfino", size: 20)
    return outgoing
}
```

I'd like to think there's a simpler way to do this. Whichever way you work, make sure it will also work in the event of other changes to your button, such as some other event setting `isEnabled` to `false` on it.

Comment: I figured it out, it appears that buttonToResize has to be set to Default style, the code does not work with Custom style set. 
In order for it to work with with Custom style, I should use AttributedTitle.
Thank you for your response and time.

Comment: It's good to know there's a simpler solution. You should write up yours and mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this

```
struct MyView: View {
  @State var pressed: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      withAnimation { 
        pressed = true 
      }
    }) {
      Text("Hello")
    }
    Button(action: {
    }) {
      Text("Hello")
         .font(pressed ? .system(size: 40) : .system(size: 20))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am new to swift. Is it possible to express the code in UIKit manner?

Comment: Oh I see that you are using UIKit...well I will leave this here for those who want to know how it could be solved in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet weak var buttonToResize: UIButton!
  
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    }
  }
```

This should solve the problem. Use the sender tag instead of the IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

Cowirrie analysis made me think of this solution (tested)

```
@IBAction func testX(_ sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1)  { 
        sender.titleLabel?.font = sender.titleLabel?.font.withSize(32) 
    }
}
```